# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am fixing bugs on this & I keep on getting "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression" error.

```
const CHARTID = "chart_id";
const FIELDID = "field_id";
const TIMEFILTERVALUE= "time_filter_input";
const TIMEFILTERUNIT = "time_filter_type"
const UNITFILTER = "unit_filter";

const constrcutFilterOptions = (field_id, chartId, timeFilterType, timeFilterUnit, unit)=> {

  var filterObj = {};
  !_.isNil(field_id) ? filterObj[FIELDID] = field_id : null;
  !_.isNil(chartId) ? filterObj[CHARTID] = chartId : null;
  !_.isNil(timeFilterType) ? filterObj[TIMEFILTERUNIT] = timeFilterType : null;
  !_.isNil(timeFilterUnit) ? filterObj[TIMEFILTERVALUE] = timeFilterUnit : null;
  !_.isNil(unit) ? filterObj[UNITFILTER] = unit : null;

  return filterObj;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should write your assignments before ternary conditions:

```js
const CHARTID = "chart_id";
const FIELDID = "field_id";
const TIMEFILTERVALUE= "time_filter_input";
const TIMEFILTERUNIT = "time_filter_type"
const UNITFILTER = "unit_filter";

const constrcutFilterOptions = (field_id, chartId, timeFilterType, timeFilterUnit, unit)=> {

  var filterObj = {};
  filterObj[FIELDID] = !_.isNil(field_id) ? field_id : null;
  filterObj[CHARTID] = !_.isNil(chartId) ? chartId : null;
  filterObj[TIMEFILTERUNIT] = !_.isNil(timeFilterType) ? timeFilterType : null;
  filterObj[TIMEFILTERVALUE] = !_.isNil(timeFilterUnit) ? timeFilterUnit : null;
  filterObj[UNITFILTER] = !_.isNil(unit) ? unit : null;

  return filterObj;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the if conditional statements instead of writing it as an expression.

e.g:

```
{ nextCell?.getElementsByTagName("input")?.length > 0 ? nextCell?.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].focus() : nextCell?.getElementsByTagName("select")?.length > 0 ? nextCell?.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].focus() : ""; } solution:-
function setKeyboardTabEvent(nextCell: any): () => void{ return ()=>{ if (nextCell?.getElementsByTagName("input")?.length > 0){ nextCell?.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].focus(); } if (nextCell?.getElementsByTagName("select")?.length > 0){ nextCell?.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].focus(); } };
```